# how disable eslint no-promise-executor-return?

Tags: typescript, eslint, yarnpkg, eslintrc, typescript-eslint

Is possible disable eslint  no-promise-executor-return ?

##### my file .eslintrc

```json
{
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "airbnb-base"
  ],
  "globals": {
    "describe": true,
    "it": true,
    "expect": true,
    "beforeEach": true
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "project": "./tsconfig.json",
    "tsconfigRootDir": "./"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "import"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "import/extensions": [
      "error",
      "ignorePackages",
      {
        "ts": "never"
      }
    ],
    "import/no-duplicates": "off",
    "import/no-promise-executor-return": "off",
    "@typescript/max-classes-per-file": "off",
    "max-classes-per-file": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/camelcase": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
    "no-underscore-dangle": "off",
    "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
    "no-plusplus": "off",
    "class-methods-use-this": "off",
    "no-unused-vars": "off",
    "max-len": "off",
    "no-lone-blocks": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion": "off",
    "no-restricted-syntax": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off",
    "camelcase": "off",
    "no-undef": "off",
    "no-use-before-define": "off",
    "no-shadow": "off"
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node":{
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx",".d.ts"],
        "moduleDirectory": ["src", "node_modules"]
      },
      "typescript": {}
    }
  }
}
```

#### my error lint

[image]

Comment: see https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-disable-eslint-rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're disabling the rule `import/no-promise-executor-return`, which would be a rule from the `eslint-plugin-import` set. Based on the output of eslint, it looks like you just want to disable `no-promise-executor-return`, which according to the docs is just a basic eslint rule (https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-promise-executor-return).

If you replace

```
"import/no-promise-executor-return": "off",
```

with

```
 "no-promise-executor-return": "off",
```

that should disable the rule.

Comment: Very good, thanks Ducan, now it's working as it should

Comment: Glad to hear it. Good luck with your project!